# Jolt Transformation to add new index json record before each json record

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

Input JSON

```
[
    {
        "timestamp":"2020-01-28 12:13:43,561",
        "threadno":"5",
        "loglevel":"DEBUG",
        "class":"someclassname",
        "nanoseconds":"587800052",
        "message":null,
        "stackTrace":null
    },
    {
        "timestamp":"2020-01-28 12:33:57,328",
        "threadno":"12",
        "loglevel":"DEBUG",
        "class":"someclassname",
        "nanoseconds":"6419049968",
        "message":null,
        "stackTrace":null
    }
]
```

Output JSON

```
[
    {
        "index":{
            "_index":"test",
            "_type":"doc",
            "_id":"20200128121343561"
        }
    },
    {
        "timestamp":"2020-01-28 12:13:43,561",
        "threadno":"5",
        "loglevel":"DEBUG",
        "class":"someclassname",
        "nanoseconds":"587800052",
        "message":null,
        "stackTrace":null
    },
    {
        "index":{
            "_index":"test",
            "_type":"doc",
            "_id":"20200128123357328"
        }
    },
    {
        "timestamp":"2020-01-28 12:33:57,328",
        "threadno":"12",
        "loglevel":"DEBUG",
        "class":"someclassname",
        "nanoseconds":"6419049968",
        "message":null,
        "stackTrace":null
    }
]
```

i need to add this index record before each json record { "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "doc", "_id" : "20200128121343561" } }  and _id value is derived from timestamp. Can we also add new line after each json record using jolt transformation

Answer (score 0):

The processing of your `timestamp` field to create an `_id` is a data transformation.  According to the jolt docs, you would have to write this as custom Java code.

> Currently, all the Stock transforms just effect the "structure" of the
>   data. To do data manipulation, you will need to write Java code. If
>   you write your Java "data manipulation" code to implement the
>   Transform interface, then you can insert your code in the transform
>   chain.

see https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt for details.